# my model is in magneta color

Tags: modeling

My model is magneta color (MakeHuman model) and I can't put it back.[image]

I tried to change the material and texture but it is still like this.[image]

The magneta  color is everywhere.[image]

I read the others answers but I have this problem[image]

Comment: The color is magenta, which is closer to pink than purple. That is why you didn't find this already answered. Search for "Blender Pink Texture".

Comment: Can you tell me where I have to look for pink? Because I can't in texture.

Comment: I can't find the Pink Texture. I find it in Material

Answer (score 0):

This Pink Material shows that you added an Image-Texture without adding an Image. Go to Node-Editor and check your Material properties (Added Image correctly? Connect all Shaders and Outputs?)

[image]

Use the small Button in the corner down on the left side and choose node-editor.

I made an example for how the "Node-Tree" should be although you should choose the "UV" output from "Texture Coordinate" if you've wrapped your Mesh (Not Generated as I did).

Comment: I'm sorry. Where is Note-editor?

Comment: Can you tell me what I have to do after going to Note-editor? Thanks

Comment: I already edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Excuse me but I don't know how to create "texture coordinate".

Comment: In Node-Editor hit Shift+A for ADD Menu. You find Texture Coordinate in INPUT.

Comment: Maybe this Tutorial will explain more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy92Ebe5Xmg

Comment: I'll see the tutorial but I don't know if this count  but my model was created in MakeHuman and the color of the skin, eyes....is already in

Comment: Please copy your file. Delete Hair and Clothes and upload .blend file.

Comment: I did that. It's in .blend file already.

Comment: @Meri Please ask one question at a time, stack exchange is not designed to let user ask consecutive questions... one question at a time. Your question should not be like a string of problems , which would have been more efficient if you gone onto google.com and search for tutorials on "Makehuman for blender" or learn the fundamentals about texturing before you try to juggle with makehuman. Your problem here is pretty obvious you will need to learn about how to do simple material and understand node based editing in blender.